# Select first row numeric values in SQL (Redshift) group by

Tags: sql, group-by, gis, amazon-redshift, latitude-longitude

I have a table of the following structure:

```
ID    latitude   longtitude   other..columns
A12    54.55        -43.26       .
A21    57.00        -43.25       .
V51    54.55        -44.25       .
V51    54.50        -43.25       .
A12    55.11        -43.15       .
B43    50.16        -43.25       .
```

I am grouping the table by `ID` and aggregating other columns by avg and min/max.
When it comes to the lat/long however, I want to pick a latitude by any aggregating (min or max, does not matter), and pick its equivalent longitude (e.g. for `A12` -> `54.55`&`-43.26`), rather than aggregate as average or min/max separately.

Is there a smart and simple way to build this query?

Current query looks something like:

```
select 
avg(other_columns),
min(latitude),
?(longtitude)
from table
group by ID;
```

EDIT: Clarified requirements following comments.

Comment: There is no such thing as "first pair available" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: "...the first pair available..." -- since table rows do not have any inherent ordering, there's no "first" row. You'll need to tell us what ordering to use for your sentence to make sense.

Comment: There is no column specifying the order. Let's say I pick the min latitude, I would like to pick its corresponding longitude . That is what I meant by pair (edited the question for clarification)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use `first_value()`.  Alas, though, there is no aggregation function, so you can use `select distinct` with window functions:

```
select distinct id, 
       avg(other_columns) over (partition by id),
       first_value(latitude) over (partition by id order by ? rows between unbounded preceding and current row),
       first_value(longitude) over (partition by id order by ? rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from table;
```

Or, you can use a subquery and `row_number()`;

```
select id, 
       avg(other_columns),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then latitude end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then longitude end)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by ID;
```

Comment: I might be able to add distinct indices for all rows, to use first_value()

Comment: @guyts . . . I don't think Redshift supports indexes.

Comment: I ended up using lat and long as the ordering columns, since order doesn't matter. And used first_value, however the syntax was quite different

Comment: @guyts . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "the syntax was quite different".  This is the Redshift syntax:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html.

Comment: Yes, from their examples I got the code actually to work. Was missing a key part of `rows between` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_firstlast_WF.html

Comment: @guyts . . . Of course.  That is the "frame_clause" so clearly highlighted in the documentation (sarcasm alert).  Redshift requires this in lots of places where other databases do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a pair out of latitude and longitude, e.g. by converting to string and concatenating them (I believe Redshift does not support structs, otherwise it would be better option):

```
cast(lat as string) || '&' || cast(lon as string)
```

Then select e.g. min value of this pair, and finally split it back using SPLIT_PART function.